# Layering background-color, background-image, and text

Tags: css

I want a blue background with the image above the background and then the text above the image.

Here's the code:

```css
body {
  background-color: blue;
}

#some-text {
  color: red;
  z-index: 3;
}

#display {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-image: url('./some-image.jpg'); 
  z-index: 2;
 }
```

```html
<body>
 <div id="some-text">TEXT</div>
 <div id="display"></div>
<body>
```

What is giving me trouble is the text has a blue background.

Setting the text's background to transparent doesn't correct it.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What do you want your text background color to be ?

Comment: You have no content inside #display and have no width/height therefore it is showing as 0px by 0px. Try adding a width/height to the #display class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `div` with an id of `#some-text` to `position: relative`, also you need to give the `div` with an id of `#display` a `width` and `height`.

```css
body {
  background-color: blue;
}
#some-text {
  color: red;
  z-index: 3;
  position: relative;
}
#display {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/350x150'); 
  z-index: 2;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="some-text">TEXT</div>
  <div id="display"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the background color of #some-text div to white.

```
#some-text {
    color: red;
    z-index: 3;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: This then makes the text's background white and still blocks part of the image. I'd only like the text to overlay the image.

Comment: Hmm, if background:transparent or background:none don't work, perhaps using a transparent png could do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple background like this:

```css
body {
 margin:0;
 height:100vh;
 line-height:100vh;
 background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=1069);
 background-position:center;
 background-size:auto;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-color:green;
 text-align:center;
 color:#fff;
 font-size:25px;
}
```

```html
Some text here
```

Comment: This works for a static background, but the problem for me is that I've structured it as background-color/image/text because I'm dynamically changing the image, which gets sloppy when it's part of the background itself.

Comment: @AdamWhite no it's not static, we can split the properties ;) check the update ... we can also split more if you want, and we can also rely on CSS variable